# How to use v.to.3d in GRASS GIS?

Tags: grass-gis

I am trying to use GRASS GIS for the first time.
After quite a lot of trouble I managed to create a location and a new mapset, and my shapefile is now displayed in the window "GRASS GIS Map Display" (for some reason only in 3d view).

My next step would be to use the v.to.3d module to add a value to the z-coordinate. I don't seem to get it right, first I tried to use "Search module", and when I found v.to.3d I doubleclicked and filled out the appearing form. That didn't work...
Then I tried writing it manually in the "Command console", but being a total GRASS GIS-beginner I'm not sure how to write? I get, or I think I get, that I need the command 'v.to.3d', an input, output and in some way add a height value.

Can someone please give me a hand? Exactly how can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Look at [v.to.3d](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/v.to.3d.html)

1) You choose the original layer and the resulting layer:

[image]

2) You can then use the name of the attribute column used for height field or a fixed height

[image]

And the command to use in the shell is specified at the base of the dialog window:

```
v.to.3d input=your_layer output=resulting_layer column=your_column
```

or

```
v.to.3d input=your_layer output=resulting_layer height=your_value
```

Comment: I still seem to be doing it wrong... I'm really a rookie at this, in step 1, shall I write a new name directly in the output field? And same, in step 2, 'name of attribute column...', can I write a name in the field or do I need to create the column in the attribute table first? I tried to fil out step 1 and 2, and then I hit 'run'. What am I missing here? Thanks for your patience.